When uploading a duplicate file to a sharepoint library, instead of asking "Keep Both" or "Replace" can i have it always default to "Replace"?
Just like the title asks, we have versioning control so users are always uploading new versions, would rather just have it default to Replace every time instead of asking if they want to replace or Keep Both. Thanks

Short answer: no. There is no way to set the "Replace" as a default.
Long answer: This is the way that SharePoint is built. Users can decide if they want to keep the existing file or overwrite it. With the "Replace" option, you will still be able to roll back to previous versions, but in some cases people may want to spin off a different file altogether. To keep this decision in the user's hands, the dialog will always show when uploading a file with an identical file name.
If the file is opened from the SharePoint library directly, then there is no dialog when it is saved. The dialog only shows if a file is uploaded, which may have several valid use cases, but it might be worth checking why there is a need to upload a file with an identical name instead of editing the existing one.
Edit: Depending on the tool you use, you can also edit PDF documents without first downloading them. SharePoint Maven has a video about that here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ODLvbmLYQ1c

Thanks! There are PDF files which need to be downloaded, updated, then re uploaded. Sharepoint doesn't offer a way to update PDFs within the browser? So the way the users do it it by downloading it, making the changes and then uploading it again over writing the existing file

I edited my answer and addressed that topic.

If you drag and drop files into a SharePoint library using File Explorer (mapped network drive or synced with OneDrive), and a file with the same name already exists, it will usually prompt you to replace the existing file. In some cases, depending on the browser and operating system, it might directly replace the existing file without prompting. This is the closest you can get to a direct "Replace" behavior using standard SharePoint functionality, but the lack of consistent behavior means it's not reliable.
